# SELECT first row in recursive part of table expression

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried to get the first row for a WHERE statement in a recursive table expression. Sadly i'm getting this error:

*The TOP or OFFSET operator is not allowed in the recursive part of a recursive common table expression 'cteTree'.*

Here's my SQL Query:

```
WITH cteTree AS( 
    SELECT 
        cct.CategoryID AS bla, 
        ct.CategoryID,ct.ParentCategoryID, 
        ct.Name, 
        ct.Published, 
        CASE 
            WHEN EXISTS(SELECT ProductID FROM Product WHERE ProductID = (SELECT TOP(1) ProductID FROM ProductCategory WHERE ProductCategory.CategoryID = ct.CategoryID) AND Product.Published = 1) THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
        END AS ProductExists, 
        1 As Cycle
            FROM Category AS ct 
            LEFT JOIN Category AS cct ON cct.ParentCategoryID = ct.CategoryID 
            WHERE cct.CategoryID IS NULL 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        cct.CategoryID AS bla, 
        ct.CategoryID,
        ct.ParentCategoryID, 
        ct.Name, 
        ct.Published, 
        CASE 
            WHEN cct.ProductExists = 1 THEN 1 
            WHEN EXISTS(SELECT ProductID FROM Product WHERE ProductID = (SELECT TOP(1) ProductID FROM ProductCategory WHERE ProductCategory.CategoryID = ct.CategoryID) AND Product.Published = 1) THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
        END AS ProductExists, 
        Cycle + 1
            FROM Category AS ct 
            JOIN cteTree AS cct ON ct.CategoryID = cct.ParentCategoryID 
)
SELECT * FROM cteTree
```

The problem is in the second Case statement under UNION ALL.

```
SELECT ProductID FROM Product WHERE ProductID = (SELECT TOP(1) ProductID FROM ProductCategory WHERE ProductCategory.CategoryID = ct.CategoryID) AND Product.Published = 1
```

Does someone know if there's another expression for selecting the first row in a recursive Table expression that works?

Comment: And your business logic is? Check that a product exists for each product category?

Comment: Why don't you just use a normal join? The whole thing is in an `EXISTS` anyway so it's not like you would get multiple results. Also `EXISTS(SELECT ProductID` is kind of pointless, you may as well write `EXISTS(SELECT 1` or `EXISTS(SELECT NULL`. You should also change that first `LEFT JOIN` `IS NULL` construct to a `NOT EXISTS`

Comment: The `TOP (1)` subquery you have doesn't have an `ORDER BY`, so either the `TOP (1)` shouldn't be there, or the `ORDER BY` being omitted is going to cause inconsistent results when arbitrary rows are returned each time the query is run. `CASE (SELECT TOP(1) ID FROM SomeTable) WHEN (SELECT TOP(1) ID FROM SomeTable) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` can just as easily return `1` as it can `0`, as you're not defining what the "top" row is.

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface the join worked perfect. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some tricks to use `TOP (1)` in a CTE, such as using `ROW_NUMBER` instead, or putting it into a TVF. But in your case you can just use a normal join:

> You should also use `NOT EXISTS` instead of the `LEFT JOIN` `IS NULL` construct.

```sql
WITH cteTree AS( 
    SELECT 
        cct.CategoryID AS bla, 
        ct.CategoryID,ct.ParentCategoryID, 
        ct.Name, 
        ct.Published, 
        CASE 
            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM Product p
                JOIN ProductCategory pc ON pc.CategoryID = ct.CategoryID
                WHERE p.Published = 1
            ) THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
        END AS ProductExists, 
        1 As Cycle
    FROM Category AS ct 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM Category AS cct
        WHERE cct.ParentCategoryID = ct.CategoryID 
    )
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        cct.CategoryID AS bla, 
        ct.CategoryID,
        ct.ParentCategoryID, 
        ct.Name, 
        ct.Published, 
        CASE 
            WHEN cct.ProductExists = 1 THEN 1 
            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM Product p
                JOIN ProductCategory pc ON pc.CategoryID = ct.CategoryID
                WHERE p.Published = 1
            ) THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
        END AS ProductExists, 
        Cycle + 1
    FROM Category AS ct 
    JOIN cteTree AS cct ON ct.CategoryID = cct.ParentCategoryID 
)
SELECT *
FROM cteTree
```